# preg_replace and asterisk

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I want to replace non-word non-space characters with spaces. There can be many symbol characters consecutively, so I'm using the regex below

```
[^\s\w]*
```

So, the code I'm using is:

```
$str = 'email@domain.com';
echo preg_replace('/[^\s\w]*/', ' ', $str);
```

I was expecting to get `email domain com` but I get `e m a i l  d o m a i n  c o m`, whitespaces between each character. If I remove the asterisk like following

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\s\w]/', ' ', $str);
```

then I get the desired `email domain com`. But if input is `email@@domain.com` then this regex will give `email  domain com` with two whitespaces between `email` and `domain`, which is not what I want.

Can anyone explain why `[^\s\w]*` doesn't work, and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Replace `*` with `+` - `/[^\s\w]+/`, `'/[^\s\w]*/'` matches empty spaces before each non matching char.

Comment: The `preg_replace('/[^\s\w]+/', ' ', $str)` is exactly what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew stupid me. I later realised that you were absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the asterisk matches **0 or more** instances of `[^\s\w]`. So it's matching 0 instances, and then replacing it with a space. Use plus (+) if you want to make sure there's at least one match: `/[^\s\w]+/`.